# Ignore matches from group in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

Help with Regex (javascript flavor):

This first regex (I call it "quote regex") will match everything between matching quotes (single/double): `/((?<quote>["']).*?\k<quote>)/i`

Then I have this one (lets call it "tag regex"): `/(?<=\s?)\S+:((?<quote>["']).*?\k<quote>|\(.*?\)|.*?(?=\s)|.*)/i`:

```
   This should match:
    tag:something
    tag:"something in double quotes"
    tag:'something in single quotes'
    tag:(between brackets)
    [tag] -> can be any word
```

What I need is to ignore "tag regex" from the result of "quote regex"

I tried both negative/positive lookahead/lookbehind, but it will either match everything or nothing...

Whats interesting is that using negative lookbehind (?<!) with a line break between those it shouldn't match and those it should... it works.

https://regex101.com/r/1KEHfW/1

I'm sharing a link to regex101, its "working" but I put a line break on the first line, if you delete the break line it stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here:

```
    tag:"something in double quotes"
    tag:'something in single quotes'
```

You have specified a greedy wilcard aggregator `*` so as you don't distinguish the kind of quote pairing it is matching from the first `"` upto the final `'` in the line below.  To match pairs of quotes, you need to specify something like this:

```
\"[^"]*\"|\'[^']*\'|\([^\)]*\)
```

which means one of three alternatives:

- Either a double quote, followed by any number of characters not equal to double quote, followed by double quote.
- Or a single quote, followed by any number of characters not equal to single quote, followed by a single quote.
- Or a left parenthesis, followed by any number of characters not equal to a right parenthesis (see note below), followed by a right parenthesis.

If you shorten your regexp to consider any kind of quotes, then the quotes don't pair each other, and you introduce space for wild in pattern recognition.

**Note:**  If you plan to nest parenthesis, like in arithmetic expression, there are bad news, as regular expressions can match arbitrary regular languages, but a language that allows nesting of structures like the one introduced by parenthesis is not regular, but context free, and any grammar that you can devise (and so a regular expression) to match nesting parenthesis, must limit the depth of nesting to a fixed, bounded limit.  I don't recommend you to follow the approach of using regular expressions to parse bound limited expressions, because the size of the regexps grows very quick with the maximum bounding nesting level.

Comment: you might have missed, but I'm naming the quotes `(?<quote>["'])` and then using a backreference `\k<quote>` to "close" the right one, even if there's another one inside.

Comment: both regex work, what I need is something that would exclude the results from the quotes if they are inside those of the tags. (right now I'm doing this manually in JS until I find a better solution)

Comment: well, once you have expressed them as `A|B|C` with subexpressions `A`, `B` and `C` you can make groups and include only the ones you are interested in, by rewriting the regexp as `(A)|(B)|(C)` which will only match `A` if there's a match for a regexp of type A.